# Force user to sign in to chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We are trying to develop some application , is there any way of popping up the chrome sign in dialog programmatically ? We need to force user to sign in to his chrome browser.

Comment: You should always use OAuth 2.0 for authentication within extensions. And Use the `chrome.identity API` to get OAuth2 access tokens. Follow up this: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity

Comment: nope, above comment i dont think will help. chrome identity only works if the user is signed-in. otherwise it opens a tab to sign-in but its not a "popup" dialog so the user can just ignore it so you cant force them to sign-in to use the page.